# Java Generics, how to avoid unchecked assignment warning when using class hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I want to use a method using generic parameters and returning generic result on a class hierarchy.

edit: **no** *SupressWarnings("unchecked")* answer allowed :-)

Here is a sample code illustrating my problem:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GenericQuestion {

    interface Function<F, R> {R apply(F data);}
    static class Fruit {int id; String name; Fruit(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id; this.name = name;}
    }
    static class Apple extends Fruit { 
        Apple(int id, String type) { super(id, type); }
    }
    static class Pear extends Fruit { 
        Pear(int id, String type) { super(id, type); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Apple> apples = Arrays.asList(
                new Apple(1,"Green"), new Apple(2,"Red")
        );
        List<Pear> pears = Arrays.asList(
                new Pear(1,"Green"), new Pear(2,"Red")
        );

        Function fruitID = new Function<Fruit, Integer>() {
            public Integer apply(Fruit data) {return data.id;}
        };

        Map<Integer, Apple> appleMap = mapValues(apples, fruitID);
        Map<Integer, Pear> pearMap = mapValues(pears, fruitID);
    }

      public static <K,V> Map<K,V> mapValues(
              List<V> values, Function<V,K> function) {

        Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
        for (V v : values) {
            map.put(function.apply(v), v);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

How to remove the generic exception from these calls:

```
Map<Integer, Apple> appleMap = mapValues(apples, fruitID);
Map<Integer, Pear> pearMap = mapValues(pears, fruitID);
```

Bonus question: how to remove the compilation error if I declare the fruitId Function this way:

```
Function<Fruit, Integer> fruitID = new Function<Fruit, Integer>() {public Integer apply(Fruit data) {return data.id;}};
```

I'm very confused about generics when it is dealing with hierarchy. Any pointer to a good resource about the usage of  and  will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 small changes:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){

    // ... snip

    // change nr 1: use a generic declaration
    final Function<Fruit, Integer> fruitID =
        new Function<Fruit, Integer>(){

            @Override
            public Integer apply(final Fruit data){
                return data.id;
            }
        };

    // ... snip
}

public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapValues(final List<V> values,

    // change nr. 2: use <? super V> instead of <V>
    final Function<? super V, K> function){

    // ... snip
}
```

---

For reference, read this:

> [The get-put principle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07018.html#3.0)