# Intellij Warning - Generic Unchecked Assignment

Tags: java, generics, unchecked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics, how to avoid unchecked assignment warning when using class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309922/java-generics-how-to-avoid-unchecked-assignment-warning-when-using-class-hierar)

Intellij is giving me the warning below.  Not sure how to resolve it, or even if I need to resolve it.  The warning details says it only applies to JDK 5, and I am using 6.  I am wondering if I need to respond to this, and if so, how?

Method call causing warning

```
List<T> refObject = cache.getCachedRefObject(cacheKey, List.class);
```

Method being called

```
public  <T> T getCachedRefObject(String objectKey, Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(refObjectCache.get(objectKey));
}
```

Warning details

```
Unchecked Assignment
JDK 5.0 only. Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:
    void f(HashMap map) {
        map.put("key", "value");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can resolve the cast in this case - you can't reify `List<T>` using a `Class` as a type token.

Comment: @Nambari This has nothing to do with the get-put principle. The cast is unchecked because of the raw type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having played with super type tokens for this, I don't think you can make this type-safe without making extra methods to retrieve collections from your cache and verifying if their contents are of the correct type.

Your options are:

1. Doing the above, which seems laborious
2. Suppress the unchecked cast in client code if you know it's correct.
3. Replace the client code with `List<?> refObject = cache.getCachedRefObject(cacheKey, List.class);`

The only type-safe variant of these is 3., in that it prevents you from doing operations that the compiler can't prove are type-safe. The obvious downside is that you might want to do some of these operations anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have an old version of IntelliJ.  This warning really means Java 5.0+ and AFAIK this was changed when IntelliJ supported Java 6 so the warning was there but didn't say "JDK 5.0 only" (it now has support for Java 8)

Comment: How so? I haven't tried running this through a compiler but it seems he's casting `List` to `List<T>`, there no way to make that not unchecked.

Comment: The warning is still there but IntelliJ not longer says "JDK 5.0 only." which may be confusing now. The OP might suspect that in Java 6 this is not a warning. This was used when most people were still on Java 1.4.2

Comment: Ah, I understood your answer as "upgrading IntelliJ should get rid of the warning".

Comment: @millimoose Good point. Worth clarifying.

Comment: Thanks.  Netbeans is fine with it, but Intellij issues the warning.  I have 11.1.3.  Looks like it still has the older warning text.  Maybe I'll just stick with Netbeans :)

Comment: Btw still activated in IJ 13.

Comment: I still get the same error on Java 8 and IJ 13.