# Casting a generic superclass to a subclass

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-safety

This is my first SO question, I hope it's useful enough, both for readers and myself! I've googled and ducked the world around with this for the past two days.

I have abstract model and storage classes from which concrete model and storage classes are derived:

```
abstract class Food {}

abstract class FoodStorage<T extends Food> {
    abstract void setFood(T food);
}

class Apple extends Food {}

class Basket extends FoodStorage<Apple> {
    @Override
    void setFood(Apple apple) {
        // Save that apple to the basket
    }
}
```

No problem. Now, I would like to be able to call a `save()` directly on an `Apple` instance, persisting it to its `Basket` (without having to bother about the basket), and have that implemented in the abstract classes. The best I've found yet is this:

```
abstract class Food<T extends Food<T,S>,
        S extends FoodStorage<T,S>> {

    abstract S getStorage();

    void save() {
        getStorage().setFood((T)this); // <---- Unchecked cast warning
    }

}

abstract class FoodStorage<T extends Food<T,S>, S extends FoodStorage<T,S>> {
    abstract void setFood(T food);
}

class Apple extends Food<Apple,Basket> {
    Basket basket = new Basket(); // or Basket.getInstance();

    @Override
    Basket getStorage() {
        return basket;
    }
}

class Basket extends FoodStorage<Apple,Basket> {
    @Override
    void setFood(Apple apple) {
        // Save that apple to the basket
    }
}
```

Which works, but IntelliJ gives me a warning about the unchecked cast in `save()`. Indeed, I'm casting from `Food<T,S>` to `T`.

**Question: how can I implement this `apple.save()` in a typesafe way?**

I don't want any wildcards appearing in the client code, so changing `abstract void setFood(T food);` to `abstract <Z extends Food<T,S>> void setFood(Z food);` is not the solution. (Obviously I'm avoiding `SupressWarnings("unchecked")` also).

I'm aware of [Java Generics, how to avoid unchecked assignment warning when using class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309922/java-generics-how-to-avoid-unchecked-assignment-warning-when-using-class-hierar) , of [Generics cast issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093767/generics-cast-issue) , and of [The get-put principle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07018/index.html#3.0), but I still can't get my head around it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're trying to do is casting a parent class obj to a child class obj now this should throw an unchecked warning, but you need to pass an argument that extends Food and cast it to a child class obj like Apple or Banana... If I were you I would `do void save() {
        getStorage().setFood(this);}` and override this method in each class extends food. yes more code but more solid design :/

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable)

Comment: (Thanks for the edit Anders)

Comment: +1 to @PaulBellora for the fact that leaf classes should be marked `final`. In essence the answer to that question is the same as meriton's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seems rather questionable design to have a mutual dependency between the food and its storage. A unidirectional depedency would simplify the generics greatly:

```
class Food { ... }
class FoodStorage<F extends Food> {
    void setFood(F f);
}
```

But if you insist on the mutual dependency, you can do it without a cast as follows:

```
abstract class Food<F extends Food<F, S>, S extends FoodStorage<F, S>> {
    abstract F getThis();
    abstract S getStorage();

    void save() {
        getStorage().setFood(getThis());
    }
}
abstract class FoodStorage<F extends Food<F, S>, S extends FoodStorage<F, S>> {
    abstract void setFood(F food);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was just referring to something like this but "this" is Brilliant

Comment: meh! I'd have said the same ;)

Comment: Nice, and thank you @Muhammad. About the mutual dependency I'm not particularly attached to it, I just don't see any other way of implementing `apple.save()`.

If a suggestion appears before a couple days without the mutual dependency I'll take it as an answer, other I'll validate this answer as the final one.