# Unchecked Assignment error for generic JavaBeanObjectProperty but not for ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectProperty

Tags: java, javafx, adapter

I'm struggling to understand what I need to do to not loose type information when building a JavaBeanObjectProperty for generic type T. One interesting detail is that I don't get this warning from IntelliJ for the ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectProperty.

```
public class FooWrapper<T> {
    /**
     * Decorates a Foo instance with javafx stuff
     */
    private final Foo foo;

    private final JavaBeanObjectProperty<T> value;
    private final ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectProperty<T> type;

    public ParameterWrapper(Foo toWrap) {
        this.foo = toWrap;
        try {
            this.value = new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<T>()
                    .bean(this.foo)
                    .name("value")
                    .build();
            this.type = new ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<T>()
                    .bean(this.foo)
                    .name("type")
                    .build();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have read [Java unchecked operation cast to generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806038/java-unchecked-operation-cast-to-generic) and [Java Generics, how to avoid unchecked assignment warning when using class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309922/java-generics-how-to-avoid-unchecked-assignment-warning-when-using-class-hierar) and am none the wiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unchecked warnings are not your fault. The generic information is not kept because the API was poorly implemented. There is an *unresolved* issue regarding this: [JDK-8152399](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152399). The issue is labeled as an "enhancement" but I'd consider it a bug.

The problem is caused by the fact nearly all the methods of [`JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.html) return *raw types*. The only exception to this is `build` which returns `JavaBeanObjectProperty<T>`. This doesn't matter, however, because by the time you've called `build` you've lost the type information from calling `bean` and `name`. Unfortunately, this means there's nothing you can do to *legitimately* get rid of the warning—you can only suppress it.

```
public class FooWrapper {

  private final Foo delegate;

  private final JavaBeanObjectProperty<SomeType> value;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Reason: Bad API
  public FooWrapper(Foo delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    try {
      value = JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.create()
          .bean(delegate)
          .name("value")
          .build();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }

}
```

This uses [`@SuppressWarnings`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) to suppress the unchecked warnings. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java). It's good practice to apply `@SuppressWarnings` to the narrowest scope possible so as to avoid suppressing other, useful warnings.

---

For comparison, look at the method signatures of [`ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/adapter/ReadOnlyJavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder.html). They all return the generic type.